# What does the `npm i` command do?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, command

What does the `i` command do in the npm CLI?

I saw it used like this:

```sh
npm i package
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `i` flag is an alias for `install`, so

```sh
npm i package
```

is the same as

```sh
npm install package
```

From the documentation:

```
npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm install <alias>@npm:<name>
npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>
npm install <git repo url>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>

aliases: npm i, npm add
common options: [-P|--save-prod|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional|--save-peer] [-E|--save-exact] [-B|--save-bundle] [--no-save] [--dry-run]
```

Comment: `--save-peer` does not exist anymore. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 26):

The `i` command is an alias for `npm-install` alias, which is mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

You can use it with all `npm-install` flags. For example below I will install `Angular` and `live-server` using the `npm i` command:

```sh
npm i angular2@2.0.0-alpha.45 -E
npm i live-server -D
```