# What is the difference betweene 'npm i' and 'npm install'?

Tags: javascript, npm

What is the difference between `npm i` and `npm install` commands? Both install all node Modules from `package.json`.

I know that it means to install. It could be possible that there is some difference between `i` and `install`.

Comment: No difference.  Just a shortcut.

Comment: Look at documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the npm -i flag mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351292/what-does-the-npm-i-flag-mean)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is no difference, since "npm i" is an alias for "npm install". They both do the exact same thing (install or update all the dependencies in your *package-lock.json*).

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install via [CRice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6293409/crice)

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install (aliases: npm i, npm add ) (with no args, in package dir)
         npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
         npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
         npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
         npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
         npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>
         npm install <git repo url>
         npm install <tarball file>
         npm install <tarball url>
         npm install <folder>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue, there actually IS a difference: https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/53

> It seems using the abbreviated form of npm install (i.e. npm i) doesn't force the resolution of packages.